# Array slice notation in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to create a subarray from an array with slice notation in BigQuery? For example, in Postgres I can do:

```
SELECT (array[1,2,3])[1:2];
[1, 2]
```

How would I accomplish something similar in BigQuery? I believe `[OFFSET(x)]` only does a single element access, but I'm not sure how I could do some workaround to do that in BigQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by `UNNEST`ing the array and rebuilding it with `ARRAY`. Here is an example that uses a procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `my-project`.other.slice(arr ARRAY<INT64>, i INT64, j INT64)
RETURNS ARRAY<INT64>
AS ((
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT _arr from UNNEST(arr) _arr
                 WITH OFFSET WHERE offset BEWEEN i AND j
                 )
   ));
```

And invoking it as:

```
select `my-project`.other.slice([1,2,3], 1, 2)
# [2, 3]
```

Note the main limitation of the above, and that is that you have to have a defined function **for each type** so you'd either need about 15 functions (one for each type), or be able to generate the necessary SQL on the front-end (similar to a macro).